# SQL Server 2005 need to move location of full text catalog?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm looking at a SQL Server 2005 database that has the mdb and logs on the E drive, but for some reason has the full text catalog on the C drive.

How do I move it to the E drive?

Also note this is a production single stand-alone server

Comment: its not a heavy transactional DB, so logs and data are on the same drive. i know this is not optimal, but for this particular app production means executives are using it so load is light but data and up time are production level

Answer (score 1):

Get name

```
 SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'<database_name>');
```

Move

```
 ALTER DATABASE directum MODIFY FILE (NAME=sysft_directum_main_MBText,filename='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData\directum_mbtext\') GO
```

No need to physically do anything with folders and files. MSSQL will handle it on its own.

Comment: I had to remove the 'Go' at the end of the 2nd statement for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx#1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174269(v=SQL.90).aspx

1. Run the following statement.

   `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET OFFLINE`
2. Move the full-text catalog to the new location.
3. Run the following statement where logical_name is the value in the name column in sys.database_files and new_path is the new location of the catalog.

   `ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_name , FILENAME = 'new_path');`
4. Run the following statement.

   `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE;`